# Creating custom component in SpaCy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am trying to create SpaCy pipeline component to return Spans of meaningful text (my corpus comprises pdf documents that have a lot of garbage that I am not interested in - tables, headers, etc.)

More specifically I am trying to create a function  that:

1. takes a `doc` object as an argument
2. iterates over the `doc tokens`
3. When certain rules are met, yield a `Span` object

> Note I would also be happy with returning a `list([span_obj1, span_obj2])`

What is the best way to do something like this? I am a bit confused on the difference between a pipeline component and an extension attribute.

So far I have tried:

```py
nlp = English()

Doc.set_extension('chunks', method=iQ_chunker)

####

raw_text = get_test_doc()

doc = nlp(raw_text)

print(type(doc._.chunks))

>>> <class 'functools.partial'>
```

> iQ_chunker is a method that does what I explain above and it returns a list of `Span` objects

this is not the results I expect as the function I pass in as method returns a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're getting a functools partial back because you are accessing `chunks` as an attribute, despite having passed it in as an argument for `method`. If you want spaCy to intervene and call the method for you when you access something as an attribute, it needs to be

```
Doc.set_extension('chunks', getter=iQ_chunker)
```

Please see the [Doc documentation for more details](https://spacy.io/api/doc).

However, if you are planning to compute this attribute for *every single document*, I think you should make it part of your pipeline instead. Here is some simple sample code that does it both ways.

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

def chunk_getter(doc):
    # the getter is called when we access _.extension_1,
    # so the computation is done at access time
    # also, because this is a getter,
    # we need to return the actual result of the computation
    first_half = doc[0:len(doc)//2]
    secod_half = doc[len(doc)//2:len(doc)]

    return [first_half, secod_half]

def write_chunks(doc):
    # this pipeline component is called as part of the spacy pipeline,
    # so the computation is done at parse time
    # because this is a pipeline component,
    # we need to set our attribute value on the doc (which must be registered)
    # and then return the doc itself
    first_half = doc[0:len(doc)//2]
    secod_half = doc[len(doc)//2:len(doc)]

    doc._.extension_2 = [first_half, secod_half]

    return doc


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tagger", "parser", "ner"])

Doc.set_extension("extension_1", getter=chunk_getter)
Doc.set_extension("extension_2", default=[])

nlp.add_pipe(write_chunks)

test_doc = nlp('I love spaCy')
print(test_doc._.extension_1)
print(test_doc._.extension_2)
```

This just prints `[I, love spaCy]` twice because it's two methods of doing the same thing, but I think making it part of your pipeline with `nlp.add_pipe` is the better way to do it if you expect to need this output on every document you parse.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will give this a go. Why did you disable `["tagger", "parser", "ner"]`?

Comment: Purely because it runs faster that way, and for no good reason relating to your question. You should enable whatever you need for your pipeline.